# data frame filter in R

Tags: r, statistics

A bit confused about what does sign `,` mean when filter a data frame, more specifically, this line of code `df2 <- df[df$c6 <= 1 & df$c4 > 200,]`. I tried to find some online documents, but failed and I think `,` means no filter on other columns of original data frame. If anyone could comment what `,` mean when doing filter, it will be great.

I post my code in R, data and results,

**Code**

```
df <- read.csv('~/Downloads/sample.csv', sep=',', header=F, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
names(df) <- c('c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5')
df$c5 <- as.numeric(df$c5)
df$c6 <- df$c5 *1000 / df$c4
table(df$c2)
df2 <- df[df$c6 <= 1 & df$c4 > 200,]
```

**Data**

```
10321,t1,1,240,0
16123,t1,20,4492,0
19123,t2,3.1,175,0
35321,t1,3,2304,4.608
```

**Results**

```
> df
     c1 c2   c3   c4    c5 c6
1 10321 t1  1.0  240 0.000  0
2 16123 t1 20.0 4492 0.000  0
3 19123 t2  3.1  175 0.000  0
4 35321 t1  3.0 2304 4.608  2
> df2 <- df[df$c6 <= 1 & df$c4 > 200,]
> df2
     c1 c2 c3   c4 c5 c6
1 10321 t1  1  240  0  0
2 16123 t1 20 4492  0  0
```

Comment: To start with, perhaps have a look at the examples in `help("[")`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, thanks and vote up, and do not know I can even do help on `[`. :)

Comment: Certainly. I know that's not an obvious `help()` query, and thought it might be useful to you.

Comment: Sure @JoshO'Brien, vote up and have a good day. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data.frames can be referenced by rows or columns.  The format is `df[row, column]`.  If you select a row, you will return all the columns from that row.  That is what you are doing with your examples, i.e. you are filtering the rows  `df[ filter condition , ]`.

Here are some illustrations of the row and column references:

```
df[3]  #column 3
#1  1.0
#2 20.0
#3  3.1
#4  3.0
class(df[3])
#[1] "data.frame"

df[,3]  #column 3
#[1]  1.0 20.0  3.1  3.0
class(df[,3])
#[1] "numeric"

df[3,]  #row 3
#c1 c2  c3  c4 c5 c6
#3 19123 t2 3.1 175  0  0
class(df[3,])
#[1] "data.frame"

df$c6 <= 1 & df$c4 > 200
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  #Only rows 1 and 2 meet the conditions
all(df[df$c6 <= 1 & df$c4 > 200, ] == df[ c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),])
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks oshun, mark your reply as answer and vote up. :)